# Extract data from date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that it possible to extract data from date string ( data such as day, WW, WD and etc.) what I don't know is how to extract two parameters from one date row and combine them together to one "cell".
For example I have the next date `2016-09-13 09:40:30.167` and I want to extract from it the week day + WW.
The result should be "Tuesday '38"
For now I extract Day & WW by "datename" function but I have results at two different columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
select datename(dw,MyDate) + ' ' + datename(ww,MyDate)
from Wherever
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, YourDateColName) + ' ''' + DATENAME(WEEK,YourDateColName)
FROM YourTable
```